# How to find intersection between collections

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have a list of Containers, each container is an object.
in each container there are some of objects.

How can we find all duplicated objects, which are shared in two or more containers?

Each container has an ID,Name, List of objects  as property.
Each object has an ID and Name.

Please see the image :

[image]

The result should be like:

```
-------------
Object1.Name    
Object2.Name    
Object3.Name
-------------
```

I have used some incorrect code

```
  public class Container
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Top, Left, Right, Bottom;
        public List<ObjectX> Objects = new List<ObjectX>();

    }



public class ObjectX
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Top, Left, Right, Bottom;

    }


 List<Container> AllBoundaries = new List<Container>();
            List<ObjectX> all_components = new List<ObjectX>();
            Container b1 = new Container();
            b1.Name = "Boundary1";
            b1.ID = "1";
            AllBoundaries.Add(b1);

            Container b2 = new Container();
            b2.Name = "Boundary2";
            b2.ID = "2";
            AllBoundaries.Add(b2);

            Container b3 = new Container();
            b3.Name = "Boundary3";
            b3.ID = "3";
            AllBoundaries.Add(b3);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ObjectX c1 = new ObjectX();
            c1.ID = "1";
            c1.Name = "c1";
            b1.Objects.Add(c1);

            ObjectX c2 = new ObjectX();
            c2.ID = "2";
            c2.Name = "c2";
            b1.Objects.Add(c2);

            ObjectX c3 = new ObjectX();
            c3.ID = "3";
            c3.Name = "c3";
            b1.Objects.Add(c3);

            ObjectX c22 = new ObjectX();
            c22.ID = "2";
            c2.Name = "c2";
            b2.Objects.Add(c2);

            foreach (Container   bx1 in  AllBoundaries )
            {

                foreach (Container bx2 in AllBoundaries)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < bx2.Objects.Count; i++)

                        if (bx1.ID != bx2.ID)
                        {
                            List<ObjectX> query = bx1.Objects.FindAll(bx => bx.Name == bx2.Objects[i].Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(bx2.Objects[i].Name + " Distributed");
                            bx2.Objects.Remove(bx2.Objects[i]);
                        }

                }
            }
```

But this gives me all objects from 1 to 9, which is not correct.

Comment: I think the question is simple to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). How about creating a complete -self contained example (also showing the expected output) so that we can copy/paste and test it.

Comment: I don't want to create a test case which may not  be what you expect.

Comment: I wonder if the Linq `Intersect` operator would work for you

Comment: @Luc Morin it works, please see the best answer if you are interested !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of containers, you co do following:

```
var item = from c in containers
           from o in c.Objects
           group c.ContainerName by o into g
           where g.Distinct().Count() > 1
           select g.Key;
```